# Use Qt for iOS without GUI (still use native Cocoa Touch)?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, qt

I have a server written in Qt (primarily because I need to use the Qt encryption package) and I want to port it to iOS. I've checked out the Qt4iOS project, and I am able to compile my server into a `.a` library. However, I still want to use the native Cocoa Touch (Obj-C) interface of the app. I just want to be able to start the server from the app and use it.

I'm not terribly sure how to do that... Should I just call the `qt_main` function (converted from the `main` function by Qt4iOS) within my `ViewController`? Qt4iOS has instruction for apps that are completely Qt. You link the `.a` file and remove everything else and it will work. But what if I don't use Qt GUI?

Many thanks!

Comment: What happens when you try calling qt_main?

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. I want to use native iOS for the GUI, networking, and gestures but would like to re-use some code that utilizes Qt data structures, error handling, etc. I can probably port this code to use standard C++ data structures instead but am curious if it's even necessary.

Comment: Have you come up with a solution for this?